# slideToggle works fine except in IE, div is hidden at the end unless min-height is given?

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle, css

I have used jQuery's `slideToggle` on a `<div>` to give the good old 'dropdown' effect.

I had it working exactly how I wanted in chrome. I then tried it in IE and came across something quite odd.. I could see the animation fine, the `<div>` would expand to its full height, but then when the animation finished, the `<div>` would disappear?

I tried a few different things to stop it doing it and it turns out that giving the `<div>` any `min-height` (I gave it 1px) allows it to work.

I'd really like to know why it's neccessary to give a `min-height` in IE to make this function work properly? It's no big deal having it there but I'd rather understand *why* I have to have it there. Code below.

**The HTML Structure**

```
<div class="home_popConfiCont rbAll">
<div class="home_popConfiHead">Your Confidential Details<div class="arrow-up"></div></div>
<div class="home_popConfiBody">
    Lots and lots of text
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    var confOpen = 0;
    $(".home_popConfiHead").click(function(){
        if(confOpen){
            $(".arrow-up").attr("class","arrow-up");
            $(".home_popConfiBody").stop(true, true).slideToggle(100);
            confOpen = 0;
        }
        else{
            $(".arrow-up").attr("class","arrow-up arrow-down");
            $(".home_popConfiBody").stop(true, true).slideToggle(100);
            confOpen = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

**The CSS applied to the said `<div>`:**

```
.home_popConfiBody{padding:5px 5px 0 5px; display:none;line-height:20px;min-height:1px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into the "hasLayout" issue.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

There are a number of things that can give your div a layout, you have discovered one of them: min-height. In addition to min-height you can also use these values (taken from the referenced article):

- display: inline-block
- height: (any value except auto)
- float: (left or right)
- position: absolute
- width: (any value except auto)
- writing-mode: tb-rl
- zoom: (any value except normal)4
- min-height: (any value)
- max-height: (any value except none)
- min-width: (any value)
- max-width: (any value except none)
- overflow: (any value except visible)
- overflow-x: (any value except visible)
- overflow-y: (any value except visible)5
- position: fixed

I think people will generally use **zoom: 1** to trigger layout because it doesn't have any noticeable visible effect on the page contents.

If the div I am toggling has floated elements inside of it, then I will generally apply an **overflow: hidden;** to the div. This causes the div to expand to the height of the floated elements inside.